# Only Return First Dated Row From Joined Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - SQL Server database.

I have two tables - the first one is a table with all of our clients. The second table, the one I'm trying to join, is a table with all of the changes to clients profiles.

What I want is the earliest date_changed, and the info associated with that record, for each and every client.

The client table, for a specific client, contains:

```
client_code | first_name | last_name | zip_postal_code
------------|------------|-----------|----------------
168187      | Trees      | Karoline  | n
```

The changes table for this client has many records:

```
client_code | clerk_changed | date_changed
------------|---------------|------------------------
168187      | taranab       | 2017-03-18 10:37:00.000
168187      | taranab       | 2017-03-18 10:37:00.000
168187      | taranab       | 2017-03-18 10:37:00.000
168187      | taranab       | 2017-03-18 10:37:00.000
168187      | taranab       | 2017-03-18 10:37:00.000
168187      | taranab       | 2017-03-18 10:37:00.000
168187      | taranab       | 2017-03-18 10:37:00.000
168187      | taranab       | 2017-03-18 10:37:00.000
168187      | taranab       | 2017-03-18 10:37:00.000
168187      | taranab       | 2017-03-18 10:37:00.000
168187      | saml          | 2017-04-21 09:36:00.000
168187      | matijay       | 2017-04-22 06:22:00.000
```

Running the query:

```
SELECT client.client_code, client.first_name, client.last_name, client.zip_postal_code, clerk.clerk_changed, clerk.date_changed
FROM maclient client
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(date_changed) AS 'date_changed', client_code, clerk_changed
    FROM maclntchg
    GROUP BY client_code, clerk_changed
) AS clerk ON client.client_code = clerk.client_code
WHERE client.client_code > '104' AND ((client.country_code = 'ca' AND LEN(client.zip_postal_code) <> 7) OR (client.country_code = 'us' AND LEN(client.zip_postal_code) <> 5)) AND client.zip_postal_code <> 'N/A' AND client.client_code = '168187'
ORDER BY clerk.clerk_changed, clerk.date_changed, client.last_name
```

Returns:

```
client_code | first_name | last_name | zip_postal_code | clerk_changed | date_changed
------------|------------|-----------|-----------------|---------------|------------------------
168187      | Trees      | Karoline  | n               | matijay       | 2017-04-22 06:22:00.000
168187      | Trees      | Karoline  | n               | saml          | 2017-04-21 09:36:00.000
168187      | Trees      | Karoline  | n               | taranab       | 2017-03-18 10:37:00.000
```

Instead of the expected result:

```
client_code | first_name | last_name | zip_postal_code | clerk_changed | date_changed
------------|------------|-----------|-----------------|---------------|------------------------
168187      | Trees      | Karoline  | n               | taranab       | 2017-03-18 10:37:00.000
```

Comment: always tag the SQL version. it will be helpful to provide you the best answer

Comment: Who is `Thompson`?

Comment: 11.0.2100.60 / SQL Server 2016. And typo, fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT client.client_code, client.first_name, client.last_name, client.zip_postal_code, clerk.clerk_changed, clerk.date_changed
FROM maclient client
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 date_changed AS 'date_changed', client_code, clerk_changed
    FROM maclntchg clerk
    WHERE client.client_code = clerk.client_code
    ORDER BY date_changed ASC
) 
WHERE client.client_code > '104' AND ((client.country_code = 'ca' AND LEN(client.zip_postal_code) <> 7) OR (client.country_code = 'us' AND LEN(client.zip_postal_code) <> 5)) AND client.zip_postal_code <> 'N/A' AND client.client_code = '168187'
ORDER BY clerk.clerk_changed, clerk.date_changed, client.last_name
```

Another one:

```
SELECT client.client_code, client.first_name, client.last_name, client.zip_postal_code, clerk.clerk_changed, clerk.date_changed
FROM maclient client
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY client_code ORDER BY date_changed ASC) row_num, date_changed AS 'date_changed', client_code, clerk_changed
    FROM maclntchg 
) clerk ON client.client_code = clerk.client_code AND clerk.row_num = 1
WHERE client.client_code > '104' AND ((client.country_code = 'ca' AND LEN(client.zip_postal_code) <> 7) OR (client.country_code = 'us' AND LEN(client.zip_postal_code) <> 5)) AND client.zip_postal_code <> 'N/A' AND client.client_code = '168187'
ORDER BY clerk.clerk_changed, clerk.date_changed, client.last_name
```

Comment: I like the second one. Is that grouping them by date changed, then just selecting the earliest date?

Comment: Yes. It gives row_number for every group of client_code starting from min date (ORDER BY date). This functions are called as WINDOW functions they are similar to the aggregate functions, but they do not group records together. You can use MIN, MAX and other ones like that.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer and explanation. Works like a charm!

Comment: @WolfieeifloW just for your reference. It is quite easy to you to provide table definition and even script INSERTs for these tables, however that would help you a lot to get the best answer as currently I couldn't even be able to test that I wrote everything right :)

Comment: @WolfieeifloW You should take your filters out of your where clause if you want this for each and every client code. (`client_code > '104'` and `client_code = '168187'`)  Having both is redundant anyway.

Comment: @AaronDietz I guess that he added the last filter just to get the right data for the question.

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev great suggestion, I will do so in the future! And yes, the `168187` was just for testing.